# Unable to close modalpanel popup window after file download JSF1.2?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using jsf1.2, the below code is in my xhtml file, this code is from a popup on click of save it will hit the respective bean method and a file will get downloaded. The requirement is that if any validation error occurs the error should get displayed in that popup itself and if no validation error is there the file should get downloaded and the popup should get closed automatically. I know that oncomplete event does not work with `<a4j:htmlCommandLink>` or `<h:commandLink>`  tag. I tried googling a lot but could not find any optimal solution. I would be very helpful if someone helps me. Currently the file is getting downloaded but the popup is not getting closed automatically, and if any validation error is there it is getting displayed in mainpage from where the popup is called. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <rich:modalPanel id="strategyModalPanelId"
        resizeable="true" style="text-align:left">
        <h:form id="dummyform">
            <rich:panel styleClass="">
                <a4j:htmlCommandLink styleClass="button color"
                    id="copystratgyid"
                    value="Save"
                    action="{BackingBean.saveStrategy}"
                    style="width: 48px;"
                    oncomplete="onCompletePopUp('strategyModalPanelId');">
                    <i class="icon-ok-sign button-icon"></i>
                </a4j:htmlCommandLink>
            </rich:panel>
        </h:form>
    </rich:modalPanel>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Why not use just `a4j:commandLink`? It supports oncomplete. In case that still doesn't work show the code of the `onCompletePopup` function.

Comment: Hi @Makhiel, in oncompletepopup function is used only for closing the popup. The thing is with a4j:commandLink the data that we have in stream is getting displayed in the page and not getting downloaded as file. In the action we have a method for downloading the received stream in file.

Comment: Ah right, you can't download a file with AJAX, however if there's no response coming from the server you also cannot use oncomplete. Can't you do the validation before showing the modal panel?

Comment: @Makhiel : In that modalpanel there are other dropdown based on that we are saving the data and getting the result from db that result we need to save it as a file and while submit if any validation error is there we need to display it in the modalpanel. We cannot do the validation before showing modal panel as we need user inputs. Clients can accept even if at least the file is getting downloaded and the modalpanel getting closed. Any any validation error can be displayed in the main page.

Comment: The idea is that when the user clicks the download button the validation would have already happened. Sounds like you can do the validation when the user selects something in the dropdown.